# How do I find out why my OpenGL ES 2.0 shader is failing to compile (Android)?

Tags: android, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I have a vertex shader and a fragment shader in OpenGL ES 2.0 running on Android.
The vertex shader compiles correctly, then the fragment shader fails to compile. I have compiled it with the following:

```
int shader = glCreateShader(type);
glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode); //Inputting the source code via the string shaderCode
glCompileShader(shader); //Attempting to compile

final int[] status = new int[1];
glGetShaderiv(shader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status,0);
```

`status` returns as 0 after for one of the shaders but not the other.
I believe this is a failed compile?
How can I find out where in my shader the problem occurred?
Is there an error message somewhere?

Thank you,

Comment: [`glGetShaderInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml)?

Comment: I'm using Java (written in Android Studio), that is a C specification so I can't copy it.

Comment: Well, now that you know the name of the function it should be easy for you to search for information on how to use it from Java.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I did Google it after commenting and found what I needed thanks.

Comment: If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a nice tool you can try [Android GLTracer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html)

> Tracer is a tool for analyzing OpenGL for Embedded Systems (ES) code in your Android application. The tool allows you to capture OpenGL ES commands and frame by frame images to help you understand how your graphics commands are being executed.

Comment: That sounds good, does it link in with Android Studio? Can I use Tracer when I'm running in debug mode in Android Studio (using an emulator or a physical phone)?

Comment: You can find it in Tools > Android Device Monitor  and from there you can follow instructions from [mobile-tracer-opengl-es](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/tasks/mobile-tracer-opengl-es/)